# WPF: Displaying image from access database?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want to display the image that i saved from my access database. nut i can't reverse on how to convert the binary to an image... This is the way i saved my image using recorset.

```
Dim Stream As FileStream
            Dim Reader As StreamReader
            Stream = New FileStream(tpath.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Reader = New StreamReader(Stream)
            Dim ImgData(Stream.Length - 1) As Byte
            Stream.Read(ImgData, 0, Stream.Length - 1)

            rs("logo").Value = ImgData
```

Please help me on how can i show it in an image control. thank you.

```
 If sdr.HasRows Then
                sdr.Read()
                Ebrdesc.Text = sdr.Item("comp_desc")
                Ebrimage.Source = ??????????

  End If
```

Hope someone cuold help and give me some pointers. thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with vb.net but does [this](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/ado.net-reading-and-writing-blob-in-vb.net) help?